# how reconnect django signals after disconnected from a for loop formset

Tags: python, django, django-signals, formset

i want send signals only for one view in a formset , i disconnected the signal after the first loop , now i want to reconnect the signal for a new view

views.py

```
def ProductOrderCreate(request):

if request.method=='GET':
    formset = ProductFormSet(request.GET or None)

elif request.method=='POST':
    formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:

            product = form.cleaned_data.get('product')
            quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')

            ProductOrder(product=product , 
                            quantity=quantity).save()         
    signals.pre_save.disconnect(create_order_instance,sender=ProductOrder)

        return redirect('/orders/')


return render(request , 'create_product_order.html' , 
    {'forms':formset})
```

signals

```
@receiver(pre_save , sender=ProductOrder)
def create_order_instance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Order.objects.create()

pre_save.connect(create_order_instance,sender=ProductOrder)

@receiver(pre_save,sender=ProductOrder)
def create_ordering(sender,instance,**kwargs):
if not instance.ordering:
    instance.ordering = Order.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
pre_save.connect(create_ordering,sender=ProductOrder)
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
products = models.ManyToManyField(Product ,through='ProductOrder') 


@property
def total(self):
    return self.productorder_set.aggregate(
        price_sum=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'), 
output_field=IntegerField()) )['price_sum'] 



class ProductOrder(models.Model):


product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='' )
ordering = models.ForeignKey(Order, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

forms.py

```
class ProductOrdering(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ProductOrder
    fields = ['product','ordering','quantity']

ProductFormSet  = formset_factory(ProductOrdering , extra=2)
```

now , i want to reconnect the signals for the next view

where should i put this code

```
signals.pre_save.connect(create_order_instance,sender=ProductOrder)
```

i put connected code after the render() but doesnt work as i expected , also outside of the function still not reconnected

Comment: If you only want to have the signal triggered in one view I would suggest not having the signal at all and adding the logic from the signal to that view

Comment: Or put in the the save method of the ModelForm

Comment: how to adding from the signal to the view?

Comment: can we do something like that from the signal itself ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logic in the view

```
    ordering = Order.objects.create()

    for form in formset:

        product = form.cleaned_data.get('product')
        quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')

        ProductOrder(
            product=product, 
            quantity=quantity,
            ordering=ordering
        ).save()
```

Comment: no , it create multi ordering number , then after saving a new instance in the same view , if we have 3 extra forms , it create 3 different ordering

Comment: They should all be assigned the same order?

Comment: yeah , create one order for multi forms , take a look at the models.py

Comment: Updated the answer, should do what you need